# Some strange moves in Polgar vs Najer (2009)

Tags: opening, analysis

In the 2009 match between Judit Polgar and Evgeniy Najer in [Richard Riordan GM Blitz](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=3707399) the following strange(?) opening sequence of the Najdorf was played

```
[White "Judit Polgar"]
[Black "Evgeniy Najer"]
[Result "1-0"]
[fen ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d3 Nf6 4. d4 cxd4 5. Nc3 a6 6. Nxd4 e5 7. Be3 Be7 8. Nb3
```

Black refuses to take the white knight on both move 5 and 7 but why? I see no horrible threat if the capture is made.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game Najer - Polgar, Richard Riordan GM Blitz, 2009 is from TWIC 767, along with the above sequence of moves. Sicilian Paulsen, White win, 78 moves. There are a large number of moveless games from the same tournament, so it looks like the event organisers had problems recording the game moves accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet a lot of money that somehow one move from either side was stored incorrectly which makes the whole game incorrect.

A possible correct version of this game may be 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Nf6 4.Nc3 cxd4 5.Nxd4 a6 6.Be3 e5 7.Nb3 Be7 Or some other permutation of those moves (e.g. play 4...cxd4 one move earlier, I chose this order since it's closer to the game given).

The cause for this probably was some kind of error with the DGT board transmission.